# Loading In Background - AndEngine GLES2

Tags: android, android-asynctask, andengine

im porting my project in AndEngine GLES2, with GLES1 versione i use this [tutorial](http://wiki.andengine.org/Loading_In_the_Background) to load assets in background, now i receive this error:

```
mActivity.onCreateScene failed. @(Thread: 'GLThread 10')
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

This is my onCreateScene method

```
    @Override
    public Scene onCreateScene() {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
        SplashScene mSplashScene = new SplashScene(this);

        IAsyncCallback callback = new IAsyncCallback() {

            @Override
            public void workToDo() {
            //Do something}

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                LoadingScene mLoadingScene = new LoadingScene(mActivity.this);
                mActivity.this.getEngine().setScene(mLoadingScene);
            }
        };

        new AsyncTaskLoader().execute(callback);

        return mSplashScene;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
new AsyncTaskLoader().execute(callback);
```

to

```
    //Fixed variant working with gles1 and gles2
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new AsyncTaskLoader().execute(callback);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Recently i found that ICS is not supporting Runnable in normal android app do above code make problem when we use this in andengine...